# How to pass some data to Android App from the browser in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to open android app form the browser and pass some data .
I did the following, In **javascript** :

```
<a href="my.special.scheme://adny/max/120">
    Open Android Application ....
</a>
```

**React-native**, **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

and finally, in the component, to get data :

```
useEffect(() => {
    Linking.getInitialURL()
        .then((url) => {
            console.log(url) // here I want to get parameters like (andy, max, 120)
        }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred ', err))
}, []);
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [here](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e) an example of how to set-up your app to support `Deep-linking`.

On the tutorial, it's done this way:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Platform, Text, Linking } from 'react-native';

class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
        this.navigate(url);
      });
    } else {
      Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  handleOpenURL = (event) => {
    this.navigate(event.url);
  }

  navigate = (url) => {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, '');
    const id = route.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/)[1];
    const routeName = route.split('/')[0];
    if (routeName === 'people') {
      navigate('People', { id, name: 'chris' })
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <Text>Hello from Home!</Text>;
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, when I ran code above , always url(in the navigate method) is null. Why ?

Comment: Nothing returns when you put a `console.log(url)` on the `componentDidMount()` ?

I see you're using hooks on your original code, so `componentDidMount()` shouldn't go well for you.

You're running on android or IOS?

Also, see [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/) how to pass parameters from react-navigation to another screen!